# Cleaning 'messy' markup rendered by ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, whitespace, markup

Ive noticed when looking at the source of a page generated in ASP.NET, the actual markup is very messy - sort of a half-assed tabbed affair with bundles of whitespace thrown in (see pic).

[image]

Can anyone suggest a technique to remove/strip this whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good article on how to override the page render method:

https://madskristensen.net/blog/remove-whitespace-from-your-aspnet-page/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it [without incurring any runtime cost](http://omari-o.blogspot.com/2009/09/aspnet-white-space-cleaning-with-no.html)